# Getting type of immutable vector in a mutable function

Tags: haskell

I have a simple in-place function which I'm using mutable vectors to implement. However, this function needs a vector which is most easily constructed using an immutable vector. Below is some toy code demonstrating the basic structure (but probably does not compile):

```
import Data.Vector.Generic as V
import Data.Vector.Unboxed as U 

myvec :: (Vector v r) => Int -> v r
myvec i = V.generate i id

f :: (MVector v r, PrimMonad m) => v (PrimState m) r -> m ()
f y = let v = myvec 10 -- what should the type of `v` be?
          --the following doesn't work since the Mutable type family is not injective:
          _ = return v `asTypeOf` unsafeFreeze y
      in do ....


main = do
   -- at the top level, I know the input can be unboxed
   let v = U.generate 10 (+(1::Int))
   v' <- thaw v
   f v'
   y <- freeze v'
   print y
```

I don't see any way for `f` to determine a (valid) immutable vector type for `v`. I would just make `myvec` generate a polymorphic *mutable* vector type, but even for the simple function above, the code for `myvec` is much uglier.

I'm looking for a solution that allows me to

1. Easily define `myvec` (as defined above) (and I don't see any way to do this cleanly with mutable vectors)
2. Uses the most specific vector type possible: for example, one solution would be to make `myvec` return a boxed vector, which can hold any `r` type. However, we are concerned about speed so if the input to `f` is a mutable unboxed vector, `myvec` should either be a mutable unboxed vector or a immutable unboxed vector.
3. I'm also trying to avoid passing in `myvec` from `main` (where the immutable type is known): we have enough information to generate the *values* locally in `f`, so passing the vector from `main` isn't necessary (except possibly for type information).

Comment: Can't you pass in the type? `f (undefined::Int) v'`? Or is there some GADT you can use instead of being so general with the `Vector` class? I'm no expert at these things; just guessing at it.

Comment: I could pass in the immutable vector type from `main` to `f` (not sure where you were going with `undefined :: Int`), but it seems crazy that I should have to do this when a perfectly valid (though ugly) alternative is to write `myvec` as a mutable function.

Comment: What do you want the vector generated by `myvec` to be populated with? If it's going to be immutable, you need to know at creation. Currently you've got it generating a vector of `Int` indexes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195497/data-families-use-cases

Comment: I'm looking at this again and wondering why you don't move the thawing and freezing out of `main` and into `f`. I could be wrong, but I imagine that any unneeded freeze/thaw pairs that result will probably be compiled away.

Comment: I think that you have the answer in your question: "Uses the most specific vector type possible". Why not write `myvec :: V.Vector U.Vector r => Int -> U.Vector r` and `f :: (M.MVector U.MVector r, PrimMonad m) => U.MVector (PrimState m) r -> m ()`? This was you are not relying on the `Mutable` type family. Note that you wouldn't have to change any code since these types are just more specific versions of the types in your question.

Comment: @rampion Sorry about the `Int`-valued vector: it's a hazard of creating a small example. The numeric type will could be `Int` or `Integer`, so we don't know if it can necessarily be unboxed.

Comment: @dfeuer I've kept the thawing/freezing in `main` because `f` will be iterated several times and I'd like to not have to keep copying my vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging around, I figured out how to write a mutable `generate` function:

```
import Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable as M
import Data.Vector.Fusion.Stream as S
import Control.Monad.Primitive

mutableGenerate :: (MVector v r, PrimMonad m) => Int -> (Int -> r) -> m (v (PrimState m) r)
mutableGenerate i f = M.unstream $ S.generate i f
```

This allows me to generate a polymorphic mutable vector, but with concise notation of an immutable vector. This seems to me like a useful function that should be included in `Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable`.